# Getting a list of running requests in ColdFusion 9 standard edition

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Does anyone know if there is a way in Adobe ColdFusion 9 standard edition to get a list of the running requests? Maybe by invoking a method from one of the CF Java objects, like coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory???

I know in enterprise you can use the server monitor for this but as we are using standard edition we do not have the server monitor available.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.seefusion.com/index.cfm?do=c_guide.configure

Comment: Thanks Travis. This is a reasonably inexpensive option, but I only require, at the moment, the single feature of seeing a list of the script names that are running. Might however be worth the $199.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the steer from @barnyr I have managed to get some code that will output a list of the currently running script names, which is exactly what I needed. Here it is for anyone who is interested.

```
<!--- Create the thread object --->
<cfobject type="JAVA" action="Create" name="thread" class="java.lang.Thread">

<!--- Get all stack traces from the thread object --->
<cfset stackTrace = thread.getAllStackTraces()>

<!--- Convert the entrySet into an array --->
<cfset stackArray = stackTrace.entrySet().toArray()>

<cfoutput>
    <!--- Loop over the entrySet array --->
    <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(stackArray)#" index="sIndex">
        <!--- Get the current thread values --->
        <cfset thisThread = stackArray[sIndex].getValue()>
        <!--- Loop over current thread values --->
        <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(thisThread)#" index="tIndex">
            <!--- Get the filename for this thread --->
            <cfset thisThreadFile = thisThread[tIndex].getFileName()>
            <!--- If the file name contains .cfm output it --->
            <cfif isDefined("thisThreadFile") AND thisThreadFile CONTAINS ".cfm">
                #thisThreadFile#<br>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Bingo! I was going to write up an example on Monday when I had CF to hand, but you beat me to it. This is pretty much what I'd have written. You may want to separate each thread from the next in the output above for clarity. Also, if you display the thread's name - thisThread.getName() then you can easily see when a thread is stuck or in an loop, because the same thread name will be running the same code each time you reload your monitoring page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after seeing just the script names and don't mind doing a little bit of manual work, you can have this for free. What you need to do is initiate a Stack trace. There's a few methods of doing this, but for me, they break down like this:

- Run ColdFusion as yourself (either by launching CF from the command line or changing the Windows Service to run as yourself), then use [jStack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) to get the stack dumps
- Leave CF running as the existing user, but [configure it to allow remote JMX connections](https://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html), then use VisualVM to connect and [use that to collect a stack dump](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/threads.html)
- Programatically get the list of threads using Thread. getAllStackTraces(). You can then do whatever you want with the data. All ColdFusion request threads start web- (for the built-in webserver) or jrpp- (for those handled through IIS or apache) so you can filter out other threads like that

If you use the first two options to get a stack dump, then I highly recommend using [Samurai](http://yusuke.homeip.net/samurai/en/index.html) to examine them. You can do several dumps 10 seconds apart and quickly identify which requests are long-running

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have tried the third but not being a Java programmer I'm struggling a little to get something meaning full. I did: `<cfobject type="JAVA" action="Create" name="thread" class="java.lang.Thread">
<cfset stackTrace = thread.getAllStackTraces()>
<cfdump var="#stackTrace.toString()#">` and this seems to give me some output that appears to contain thread ID's but nothing about the scripts. Any further advise?

Answer (score 0):

Try cftracker, it may d what you neef
https://github.com/misterdai/cfTrackercfTracker