# Issue with PUT request in ColdFusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfhttp

While working with a API , I need to make a `PUT` request to a URL along with some parameters needs to be passed as POST parameter.

Locally I have created 2 files calling.cfm and caller.cfm to test cfhttp with `PUT` request.
But each time it is throwing error `The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: cfhttp`

caller.cfm

```
<cfhttp url="http://cflocal.com/jquerySliderApp/calling.cfm" method="put">
     <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form- urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" />
     <cfhttpparam type="body" value="Deepak" >  
</cfhttp>   
<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">
```

calling.cfm

```
<cfloop collection="#FORM#" item="i">
   <cfoutput>FORM SCOPE:#form[i]#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>

<cfloop collection="#URL#" item="i">
  <cfoutput>URL SCOPE:#URL[i]#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

I am passing the parameter with `type="body"` as in  [Adobe Forum](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5264196) , someone mentioned ColdFusion sends the request body with PUT and DELETE requests, so we can format the request body as a form field (or series of form fields).

I have tried with `<cfhttpparam type="body" name="fname" value="#urlEncodedFormat("Deepak")#" >` . Still showing the same error.

I am using ColdFusion 10. Please let me know if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: anyone please suggest what mistake with my cfhttp call that it hangs my coldfusion server

Answer (score 4):

`<cfhttpparam>` doesn't do anything with the name attribute when the type="body". If you're setting the body yourself, you should be sending something like the following as the body:

```
fname=Deepak&otherparam=foo
```

As is so often the case, [Ben Nadel has your back here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2325-ColdFusion-Supports-HTTP-Verbs-PUT-And-DELETE-As-Well-As-GET-And-POST-.htm). CF Doesn't process the FORM scope for you on PUT or DELETE requests, so you'll need to process `getHttpRequestData().content` yourself in order to get at the values sent, but you can probably use the method [in this blog post](http://misterdai.yougeezer.co.uk/posts/1316/) to achieve that.

Comment: How can I pass parameter to an API with `put` request asking for parameters in formfield or form scope.

Comment: And moreover why i am getting request timeout error , while everything works fine with `post and get` request.

Comment: You mean your own API? You have two options. First, try parsing the body with the link I included, then update the FORM scope. Second, your API shouldn't really directly reference the FORM scope. That's the job of the controller code handling the request. Your real business logic should just expect a struct and not care whether it came from. You should use option 2 in my view.

Comment: If you want to see what the thread is hanging on, use the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16117508/826714 - post your stack dump and we may be able to assist you further

Comment: I am not using my own API, I need to make request to YesMail API

Comment: So the first part of my answer applies. URLEncode your parameters and set them as the request body

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49212/discussion-between-deepak-kumar-padhy-and-barnyr)