# Using ColdFusion 10's REST Services why is a post request using the PUT method with raw json body resulting in an empty string

Tags: json, rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

First off, this code snippet comes from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GkXanOqH88 and works on ColdFusion 11 but I'm running into an issue when using it on CF10.

Sending the following request:

```
PUT /rest/api/expenseAPI/user/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5080
Content-Type: application/json
authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1OTg0ODI3NzYsInRzIjoiQXVndXN0LCAyNiAyMDIwIDE1OjI5OjM2IiwidXNlcmlkIjoxfQ.DRhNXWghiGmQThe1ae8KATAfl2pO5e3-g3ERUf3MzMU

{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "email": "test@testing.com"
}
```

...to the following function should pass the JSON body to the `structform` argument however the  `structform` argument is resulting in an empty string! I've found that if I change the `httpmethod` to POST and sent a POST request then it work as expected. Is this a CF10 bug or what?

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="expenseAPI">
...
    <cffunction name="putuser" restpath="user/{id}" access="remote" returntype="struct" httpmethod="PUT" produces="application/json">
    <cfargument name="id" type="any" required="yes" restargsource="path"/>
    <cfargument name="structform" type="any" required="yes">
    
    <cfset var response = {}>

    <cfset verify = authenticate()>
    <cfif not verify.success>
        <cfset response["success"] = false>
        <cfset response["message"] = verify.message>
        <cfset response["errcode"] = 'no-token'>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset response = objUser.updateUser(arguments.id, arguments.structform)>
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn response>

</cffunction>
```

Comment: See the answer posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22244142/1636917 which also references Ben Nadel's explaination here - [ColdFusion Supports HTTP Verbs PUT And DELETE (As Well As GET And POST)](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2325-coldfusion-supports-http-verbs-put-and-delete-as-well-as-get-and-post.htm) And please stop using ColdFusion 10 AND 11.  It's time to upgrade.